# Formula Matemática JavaScript

Tags: javascript, matemáticas

Tengo un formulario con muchas operaciones, pero no soy capaz de enlazar un resultado con otro, ahora mismo solo estoy probando con 3 operaciones.
Primero calcula la cantidad por su precio unitario y lo multiplica.
Hasta este paso todo correcto.
Donde me falla es cuanod le digo el % de descuento que debe de aplicar a ese total.

Os dejo la formula de JavaScript ya que el input para mi esta correcto ya que unicamente tiene un `onkeyup`

```
function formula() {
var cantidad = document.form1.cantidad.value;
var precio_unitario = document.form1.precio_unitario.value;
var descuento_porcentaje = document.form1.descuento_porcentaje.value;

try{

   cantidad = (isNaN(parseInt(cantidad)))? 0 : parseInt(cantidad);
   precio_unitario = (isNaN(parseInt(precio_unitario)))? 0 : parseInt(precio_unitario);
   document.form1.total.value = cantidad*precio_unitario;
}

catch(e) {}

var cnt_pre_uni = document.form1.cantidad*precio_unitario
try{

   cnt_pre_uni = (isNaN(parseInt(cnt_pre_uni)))? 0 : parseInt(cnt_pre_uni);
   descuento_porcentaje = (isNaN(parseInt(descuento_porcentaje)))? 0 : parseInt(descuento_porcentaje);
   document.form1.total.value = descuento_porcentaje*cnt_pre_uni/100;
}

catch(e) {}
}
```

Lo que necesito es que el resultado de `cantidad` por `precio` lo saque a una variable `cnt_pre_uni` para poder aplicar el %

Comment: fijate que cuando creas la variable `cnt_pre_uni` la cantidad no la estas llamando desde la variable `cantidad` creada arriba; el precio unitario lo estas multiplicando por un elemento html(la linea `var cnt_pre_uni = document.form1.cantidad*precio_unitario` debería ser `var cnt_pre_uni = cantidad*precio_unitario`)

Comment: creo que ya lo arreglue, lo deje en respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error esta en la linea `cnt_pre_uni = document.form1.cantidad*precio_unitario` debido a que estas accediendo al elemento cantidad y no al valor si quieres acceder al valor debes agregar la linea `document.form1.cantidad.value` colocare el ejemplo para que comprendas mejor

```js
console.log(document.form1.cantidad);
console.log(document.form1.cantidad.value);
```

```html
<form name="form1">
<input type="text" name="cantidad" value="ejemplo"/>
</form>
```

aqui muestro el codigo funcional sin editar tus formulas; solo utilice las variables que tenias en la cabecera

```js
    function formula() {

    var cantidad = document.form1.cantidad.value;
    var precio_unitario = document.form1.precio_unitario.value;
    var descuento_porcentaje = document.form1.descuento_porcentaje.value;
    try{

       cantidad = (isNaN(parseInt(cantidad)))? 0 : parseInt(cantidad);
       precio_unitario = (isNaN(parseInt(precio_unitario)))? 0 : parseInt(precio_unitario);
       document.form1.total.value = cantidad*precio_unitario;
    }
   
    catch(e) {}

    var cnt_pre_uni = cantidad*precio_unitario
  try{

       cnt_pre_uni = (isNaN(parseInt(cnt_pre_uni)))? 0 : parseInt(cnt_pre_uni);
       descuento_porcentaje = (isNaN(parseInt(descuento_porcentaje)))? 0 : parseInt(descuento_porcentaje);
       document.form1.total.value = descuento_porcentaje*cnt_pre_uni/100;
    }

    catch(e) {}
    }
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1">
Cantidad
<br/>
<input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" onkeyup="formula()"/>
<br/>
Precio Unitario
<br/>
<input type="text" id="precio_unitario" name="precio_unitario"onkeyup="formula()"/>
<br/>
Descuento:
<br/>
<input type="text" id="descuento_porcentaje" name="descuento_porcentaje" onkeyup="formula()"/><br/>
total
<br/><input type="text" id="total" readonly />
</form>
```

Comment: Si, de todas maneras haces el calculo mal, deberias multiplicar cantidad por precio unitario y luego aplicarle el porcentaje fijate en como lo hice yo.

Comment: es tu codigo!, no hice nada  simplente hice que funcionara

Answer (score 2):

Creo que ya lo tengo, creo que estaba hacienod mal la formula y aparte tenia dos `try` y con meter todas las operaciones en uno creo que me vale, les dejo el código para que verifiquen ustedes.

```
function formula() {
var cantidad = document.form1.cantidad.value;
var precio_unitario = document.form1.precio_unitario.value;
var descuento_porcentaje = document.form1.descuento_porcentaje.value;

try{

   cantidad = (isNaN(parseInt(cantidad)))? 0 : parseInt(cantidad);
   precio_unitario = (isNaN(parseInt(precio_unitario)))? 0 : parseInt(precio_unitario);


   descuento_porcentaje = (isNaN(parseInt(descuento_porcentaje)))? 0 : parseInt(descuento_porcentaje);
   document.form1.total.value = (cantidad*precio_unitario)-(descuento_porcentaje*(cantidad*precio_unitario))/100;

catch(e) {}
}
```